# How to get difference of two csv files and write diff into 3rd file?

Tags: awk, csv, diff

I have two csv files like this;

```
422174,XN,20.99,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
421348,SB,21.99,2021-01-26,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
885176,XN,41.80,2021-11-17,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
881751,SB,12.81,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
722483,XN,67.50,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
```

Second file;

```
667843,XN,22.99,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
421348,SB,21.99,2021-01-26,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
885176,XN,41.80,2021-11-17,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
881751,SB,12.81,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
156734,XN,34.50,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
```

Output should be ;

```
667843,XN,22.99,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
156734,XN,34.50,2020-09-01,2022-01-20 20:20:28.613+00
```

How can I do this by using awk?

Comment: It seems what you want is: *"Get the lines that are in second file but not in first file"*

Comment: Do you have to use `awk`? There are better ways to achive that

Comment: as is it is difficult to answer. whare are "same" line ? all all fields revelent ? to you want "new" lines ? old "lines" ? have you had a look at `man comm` ?

Comment: Yes that is correct @EdgarMagallon and we don't have to use awk.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) explain, in words, what you need. For all we know, you want to get the first and last lines of the files. How are we supposed to compare them? ii) show us what you have tried so far so we don't waste your time with solutions you already know don't work.

Comment: Does this command work `grep -vwf file1 file2`. The command is taken from an old answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `comm` instead of `awk` for this task:

```bash
comm -13 <(sort first.csv) <(sort second.csv) > difference.csv
```

From `comm --help`:

> -1                      suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)
>
> -2                      suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)
>
> -3                      suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)

Comment: What does -13 mean?

Comment: if you are not use to unix parameters `-13` is a shot cut for `-1 -3`.

Comment: @Burak just what Archemar said. So what I'm doing there is suppressing lines that apear in both files and also I'm suppressing lines that appear in first file (it is what I said *"Get the lines that are in second file but not in first file"*)

Comment: @Burak all Unix tools have manual pages. Google it or type `man comm`.

Comment: Is there a way to find the difference by columns rather than whole row? @EdgarMagallon

Comment: @Burak I guess so but it I think it should be more complex. What columns would you like to consider?

Comment: First two rows should be considered. 667843,XN @EdgarMagallon

Comment: @Burak it's possible to do it. I only think about using `comm` with `cut` (to extract only two first columns). But it will be necessary to use `grep` or `join` perhaps. I recommend you ask another detailed question. Given that this one and what you are asking now are completely different. And I also recommend you try solving by yourself and If you have any problem then ask your question.

Comment: @Burak this is a little example about how  can you do that: `comm -13 <(cut -d ',' -f1,2 first.csv | sort) <(cut -d ',' -f1,2 second.csv | sort)` but it's still necessary  to use more tools or maybe there are shorter ways to achieve that.

Comment: But I only need first two columns to do the comparison. With cut command, I guess it will output only first two columns, right? Because right now in output.csv, there are some duplicate ids.

Comment: I asked another question @EdgarMagallon you can check there